# Cisco ASA access-lists and net config

Tags: cisco-asa, ipsec, acl, eigrp, network-access

[image]

Here are my config to this network. I found the ASA doesn’t ping through each other. Also, when I type show crypto isakmp SA and IPSec Sa, it doesn’t show anything at all. Could you guys find what’s wrong or some suggestion on this configuration for all ASAs of LA SD SF MI NY? I would really appreciate

```
ISP

Int g0/0
ip add 2.2.1.1 255.255.255.252
no shut

Int g0/1
IP add 2.2.2.1 255.255.255.252
no shut

int g0/2
ip add 2.2.3.1 255.255.255.252
no shut

int g0/3
ip add 4.4.129.1 255.255.255.252
no shut

int g0/3
ip add 4.4.128.1 255.255.255.252
no shut
```

LA, ASA 5506: 8.4 or later

---

```
!
hostname LA
!
interface G0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 2.2.1.2 255.255.255.0
 no shut
!
interface G0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.10.255.1 255.255.255.0
 no shut
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 2.2.1.1
!
!
object network INSIDE_NETWORK
 subnet 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
!
!
! Allowing ICMP through ASA.
!
!class-map inspection_default
! match default-inspection-traffic
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error
!
!service-policy global_policy global
!
!
! Allowing ICMP to ASA's inside interface from another site.
!
management-access inside
!
!
! Phase 1 (IKEv1)
!
crypto ikev1 enable outside
!
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
!
tunnel-group 4.4.128.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 4.4.128.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key LA10toNY20
tunnel-group 2.2.2.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 2.2.2.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key LA10toSF20
tunnel-group 2.2.3.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 2.2.3.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key LA10toSD20

router eigrp 1
network 10.0.0.0
red stat



!
! Phase 2 (IPSec)
!
object network N_10.10.0.0_16
 subnet 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.128.0.0_16
 subnet 10.128.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.20.0.0_16
 subnet 10.20.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.30.0.0_16
 subnet 10.30.0.0 255.255.0.0
!
access-list IPSEC_NY_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.10.0.0_16 object N_10.128.0.0_16
access-list IPSEC_SF_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.10.0.0_16 object N_10.20.0.0_16
access-list IPSEC_SD_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.10.0.0_16 object N_10.30.0.0_16
!
! NAT Exemption (No NAT)
! Packet Tracer limitation (Manual NAT is not supported.)
!
nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.10.0.0_16 N_10.10.0.0_16 destination static N_10.128.0.0_16 N_10.128.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.10.0.0_16 N_10.10.0.0_16 destination static N_10.20.0.0_16 N_10.20.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.10.0.0_16 N_10.10.0.0_16 destination static N_10.30.0.0_16 N_10.30.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 match address IPSEC_NY_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 set peer 4.4.128.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 set ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 match address IPSEC_SF_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set peer 2.2.2.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 match address IPSEC_SD_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 set peer 2.2.3.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 set ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
!
crypto map IPSEC_MAP interface outside
!
```

---

---

SF, ASA 5506: 8.4 or later

---

```
!
hostname SF
!
interface G0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
interface G0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.20.255.1 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 2.2.2.1
!
!
object network INSIDE_NETWORK
 subnet 10.20.0.0 255.255.0.0
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface




! Allowing ICMP through ASA.
!
!class-map inspection_default
! match default-inspection-traffic
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error
!
!service-policy global_policy global
!
!
! Allowing ICMP to ASA's inside interface from another site.
!
management-access inside


! Phase 1 (IKEv1)
!
crypto ikev1 enable outside
!
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
!
tunnel-group 2.2.1.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 2.2.1.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key LA10toSF20

router eigrp 1
network 10.0.0.0
red stat



! Phase 2 (IPSec)
!
object network N_10.20.0.0_16
 subnet 10.20.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.10.0.0_16
 subnet 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0


access-list IPSEC_SF_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.20.0.0_16 object N_10.10.0.0_16


! NAT Exemption (No NAT)
! Packet Tracer limitation (Manual NAT is not supported.)
!
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.20.0.0_16 N_10.20.0.0_16 destination static N_10.10.0.0_16 N_10.10.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 match address IPSEC_SF_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set peer 2.2.1.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
!
crypto map IPSEC_MAP interface outside
!
```

---

---

SD, ASA 5506: 8.4 or later

---

```
!
hostname SD
!
interface G0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 2.2.3.2 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
interface G0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.30.255.1 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 2.2.3.1
!
!
object network INSIDE_NETWORK
 subnet 10.30.0.0 255.255.0.0
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface




! Allowing ICMP through ASA.
!
!class-map inspection_default
! match default-inspection-traffic
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error
!
!service-policy global_policy global
!
!
! Allowing ICMP to ASA's inside interface from another site.
!
management-access inside


! Phase 1 (IKEv1)
!
crypto ikev1 enable outside
!
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
!
tunnel-group 2.2.1.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 2.2.1.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key LA10toSD20

router eigrp 1
network 10.0.0.0
red stat



! Phase 2 (IPSec)
!
object network N_10.30.0.0_16
 subnet 10.30.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.10.0.0_16
 subnet 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0


access-list IPSEC_SD_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.30.0.0_16 object N_10.10.0.0_16


! NAT Exemption (No NAT)
! Packet Tracer limitation (Manual NAT is not supported.)
!
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.30.0.0_16 N_10.30.0.0_16 destination static N_10.10.0.0_16 N_10.10.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 match address IPSEC_SD_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 set peer 2.2.1.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 set ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 30 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
!
crypto map IPSEC_MAP interface outside
!
```

---

---

MI, ASA 5506: 8.4 or later

---

```
!
hostname MI
!
interface G0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 4.4.129.2 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
interface G0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.129.255.1 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 4.4.129.1
!
!
object network INSIDE_NETWORK
 subnet 10.129.0.0 255.255.0.0
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface




! Allowing ICMP through ASA.
!
!class-map inspection_default
! match default-inspection-traffic
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error
!
!service-policy global_policy global
!
!
! Allowing ICMP to ASA's inside interface from another site.
!
management-access inside


! Phase 1 (IKEv1)
!
crypto ikev1 enable outside
!
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
!
tunnel-group 4.4.128.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 4.4.128.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key NY10toMI20

router eigrp 1
network 10.0.0.0
red stat


! Phase 2 (IPSec)
!
object network N_10.129.0.0_16
 subnet 10.129.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.128.0.0_16
 subnet 10.128.0.0 255.255.0.0


access-list IPSEC_MI_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.129.0.0_16 object N_10.128.0.0_16


! NAT Exemption (No NAT)
! Packet Tracer limitation (Manual NAT is not supported.)
!
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.129.0.0_16 N_10.129.0.0_16 destination static N_10.128.0.0_16 N_10.128.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 match address IPSEC_MI_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set peer 4.4.128.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
!
crypto map IPSEC_MAP interface outside
!
```

---

---

NY, ASA 5506: 8.4 or later

---

```
!
hostname NY
!
interface G0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 4.4.128.2 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
interface G0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.128.255.1 255.255.255.252
 no shut
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 4.4.128.1
!
!
object network INSIDE_NETWORK
 subnet 10.128.0.0 255.255.0.0
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface




! Allowing ICMP through ASA.
!
!class-map inspection_default
! match default-inspection-traffic
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp 
  inspect icmp error
!
!service-policy global_policy global
!
!
! Allowing ICMP to ASA's inside interface from another site.
!
management-access inside


! Phase 1 (IKEv1)
!
crypto ikev1 enable outside
!
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
!
tunnel-group 4.4.129.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 4.4.129.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key NY10toMI20
tunnel-group 2.2.1.2 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 2.2.1.2 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key LA10toNY20

router eigrp 1
network 10.0.0.0
red stat


! Phase 2 (IPSec)
!
object network N_10.128.0.0_16
 subnet 10.128.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.129.0.0_16
 subnet 10.129.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.128.0.0_16
 subnet 10.128.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network N_10.10.0.0_16
 subnet 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0


access-list IPSEC_MI_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.128.0.0_16 object N_10.129.0.0_16
access-list IPSEC_NY_ACL extended permit ip object N_10.128.0.0_16 object N_10.10.0.0_16


! NAT Exemption (No NAT)
! Packet Tracer limitation (Manual NAT is not supported.)
!
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.128.0.0_16 N_10.128.0.0_16 destination static N_10.129.0.0_16 N_10.129.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static N_10.128.0.0_16 N_10.128.0.0_16 destination static N_10.10.0.0_16 N_10.10.0.0_16 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 match address IPSEC_NY_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 set peer 2.2.1.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 set ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 match address IPSEC_MI_ACL
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set peer 4.4.129.2
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set ikev1 transform-set IPSEC_SET
crypto map IPSEC_MAP 20 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
!
crypto map IPSEC_MAP interface outside
```

Comment: For starters, please use the { } function to properly format the configs.

Comment: Sorry, the long text. That would be take longer time to format

Comment: You can select a whole config and just hit the `{ }` symbol above.

Comment: I snapshot the photos, I hope you can see it. Sorry, I am not comfortable using symbol and it doesn’t work as shows to my end

Comment: First half object network to net config without any label belong to SF ASA

Comment: Gosh - no snapshots for text PLEASE! That is completely unreadable. Above the edit window, there's a `{ }` icon that formats any selected text as preformatted, useful for configs and code.

Comment: We need to see the configuration of the ISP-3650

Comment: Can each device ping its gateway address?

Comment: yes, but can't ping other 10.0.0.0 network

Comment: Please include the full ISP 3650 configuration.  Did you enable routing?

Comment: do you mean ASA routing? it has default routing route to ISP

Comment: I mean routing on the 3650. Please include the full configuration.

Comment: I just use eigrp on 10.0.0.0 network on all ASA and 3650

Comment: We need to see the FULL configuration of the ISP 3650. Also show IP route on that device.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each ASA has to know the networks behind the others - either use static routes or set up a routing protocol like OSPF.

Without proper routing, all traffic goes to the default gateway.

Comment: yes, it has eigrp. but only know inside network

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basics. Ping from one ASA to another on the outside IP to verify it is reachable. Then enable 'debug crypto ipsec' 'debug crypto ikev1' 'debug crypto isakmp' and watch the log output. Generate traffic from a host inside a firewall destined to an IP address that should be available through the VPN tunnel. See what the error log or debug output indicates. Proceed to troubleshoot based on log output.